# Programmatically include layout in Android (replicating the <include/> tag

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have multiple skeleton layouts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       ...
</merge>
```

I need to wrap this layout in a LinearLayout, but don't want to make multiple xml files since they'd just have a linearlayout and an include tag, like this...

```
<LinearLayout    
    <include layout="@layout/layout1"
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way I can achieve the same effect as that @layout/layout1 programmatically? Like choose which layout to include? I'm inflating this layout for a ViewHolder in a recyclerview, and right now I'm doing this.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewHolder vh = null;
    View inflatedView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cool_layout, parent, false);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, (LinearLayout)inflatedView, true);
            vh = new ViewHolder(inflatedView);
        case 2:
            inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cool_layout, parent, false);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, (LinearLayout)inflatedView, true);
            vh = new ViewHolder(inflatedView);
```

It makes two inflate() calls which probably isn't a good idea, so I'm looking for an alternative aside from making a bunch of xml files.

Answer (score 2):

**this will be in your parent root...**

```
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
           android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
           android:layout="@layout/mySubTree"
           android:layout_width="120dip"
           android:layout_height="40dip" />
```

**in java file**

```
ViewStub stub = new ViewStub(this);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.mySubTree);
stub.inflate();
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the switch to select your layout then have only one inflater call afterward:

```
    int layout = 0;

    switch(mLayoutType){
        case "layout_1":{
            layout = R.layout.layout_1;
            break;
        }
        case "layout_2":{
            layout = R.layout.layout_2;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Invalid layout type.");
        }
    }

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
```